# How to resize jQuery Mobile elements like Flip buttons, Lists etc for desktop browsers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile for my application that runs mainly on desktop browsers. The only problem I'm facing is the elements are stretched out as per the screen size.

For example: If viewed on a large monitor, the buttons take the whole screen size.

I was wondering, how can I control the size of these elements.

I was wondering, if I made a wrong choice by selecting jQM for desktop usage. But I really like the jQuery Mobile styles. Any alternatives for this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>jQuery Mobile Testing Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
         <a href="#" rel="external" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="b"> Dashboard </a>
        <h1>Testing Document</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <form method="POST" action="#" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider"> <h3> Services </h3> </li>
             <li data-theme="a"> Class 1 </li>
            <li> <label for="flip-b">Element1</label>
                <select name="element1" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li>   
            <li> <label for="flip-b">Element2</label>
                <select name="element2" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li> 
             <li> <label for="flip-b">Element3</label>
                <select name="element3" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li> 
             <li> <label for="flip-b">Element4</label>
                <select name="element4" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li> 
             <li> <label for="flip-b">Element5</label>
                <select name="element5" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li> 
             <li> <label for="flip-b">Element6</label>
                <select name="element6" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
             </li> 
              <li> 
                    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Main Location</label>
                       <select name="main_location" id="select-choice-1">
                          <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                          <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                          <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                          <option value="SA">SA</option>
                          <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                          <option value="NT">NT</option>
                          <option value="WA">WA</option>
                          <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                        </select>                     
              </li> <!-- Select Menus: Main Location-->        

            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of Field Contain div tag -->   
    <button type ="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="b">Search</button>    
   </form>
   </div> <!-- End of Content div tag --> 
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h6>2012 &copy</h6>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @PhillPafford Thanks for your reply. I've posted the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQM Docs that will help:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/content/content-grids.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/forms-all.html

UPDATE:

Using the methods from the links I suggested:

- http://jsfiddle.net/xLdKd/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/xLdKd/3/embedded/result/ (Full page view)

Comment: Could you please explain your update. What should I need to do with JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a test environment to execute code in, for the Full page view I have provided I've demonstrated you search button is no longer the full width of the screen. Applying some of the techniques found in the jQM Documentation will help you make the needed changes you want